# CSV data loading give Not enough columns given to draw the requested chart

Tags: javascript, csv, google-visualization

Please see I already saw related threads but they did not help.

I am creating line chart which is exactly same format as : https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Example

Difference is I am using csv data, which is correct way to read from csv.

code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://jquery-csv.googlecode.com/files/jquery.csv-0.71.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
       $.get("Chart3-data1.csv", function(csvString) {
          var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar});
          var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);
         var options =
        {
                title: 'Company Performance'
         };
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('gauge'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
});
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="gauge" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

csv data is in this form:

```
"Date,Term,Segment,Visitor"
"2014/01/01,2014/01/01 - 2014/01/31,All visitors,2"
"2014/01/01,2014/01/01 - 2014/01/31,New user,0"
"2014/01/01,2014/01/01 - 2014/01/31,Mobile traffic,0"
"2014/01/02,2014/01/01 - 2014/01/31,All visitors,7"
"2014/01/02,2014/01/01 - 2014/01/31,New user,1"
"2014/01/02,2014/01/01 - 2014/01/31,Mobile traffic,0"
"2014/01/03,2014/01/01 - 2014/01/31,All visitors,5"
"2014/01/03,2014/01/01 - 2014/01/31,New user,0"
"2014/01/03,2014/01/01 - 2014/01/31,Mobile traffic,0"
"2014/01/04,2014/01/01 - 2014/01/31,All visitors,3"
"2014/01/04,2014/01/01 - 2014/01/31,New user,1"
"2014/01/04,2014/01/01 - 2014/01/31,Mobile traffic,0"
```

Error:

```
Not enough columns given to draw the requested chart
```

Comment: Your CSV data is misformatted, you shouldn't have quotes around each line.

Comment: Why is the Quotes there in csv?

Comment: @Barmar: thanks, but it is auto generated csv file. And I can not change it. Is it possible to deal with this short of data

Comment: @ShijuKBabu: please see my answer to Barmar

Comment: Because of double quotes, the whole line is taking as single field I guess. You should try not to escape the quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put quotes around each line in the CSV file. In CSV, you put quotes around an individual data element when it contains a delimiter, e.g. to allow values that contain comma. So what you've written makes each line a single value, not 4 values.

If you can't change the input data, you can remove the extraneous quotes from the string before processing it as CSV:

```
csvstring = csvstring.replace(/^"|"$/gm, '');
```

Comment: thanks, is it possible that I convert in some meaning full format before I process it?

Comment: thank you buddy, but now it says `All series on a given axis must be of the same data type` any idea for this?

Comment: You might need to remove the first line that contains the column names.

Comment: There's a `startIndex` option, but the documentation says it's not implemented.

Comment: Yes. well,removing forst line also does not help. now it says `Error: Unknown header type: 2`

Comment: Then maybe the error message is correct, and you have some lines with different types of data. It looks correct in the sample you showed, so it must be in other lines.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with the Google Visualization tool, and I don't feel like researching it to try to figure out what you're doing wrong. Maybe it's because the Visitor column is a number, but the Term and Segment columns are strings.